# Rails display table data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have developed rails app with three classes.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :observations

end

class Observation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  has_one :rainfall
  has_one :temperature
  has_one :winddirection
  has_one :windspeed
  has_one :dewpoint

end


class Rainfall < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :observation

end
```

Railfall is related to Observation through an observation_id and Observation is related to Location through a location_id.

If i go to console and type something like:
Location.all.first.observations.first.rainfall.value
it returns me the data in value column of rainfall

However when i want to combine all the info in rails in a table and in my view/location/index.html.erb i put:

```
<tbody>
    <% @locations.each do |location| %>
      <tr>

        <td><%= location.name %></td>



        <% unless @observations = nil %>

        <% location.observations.each do |obs| %>
        <td><%= obs.name %></td>

        <% unless @rainfalls = nil %>
        <td><%= obs.rainfalls.value %></td>


    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I get an error:

```
    undefined method `rainfalls' for Observation:0x00000004219068>
```

I have spent the last 5 hours trying just about everything i can and am getting a tad frustrated....any ideas?

Note i have a locations controller but observation and rainfall were generated as models, so do not. Am thinking i need to add something to my location controller, just can't work out what, and I am unsure why it returns the correct data in console, just no in app.

Comment: It should be **rainfall** as it's a **has_one** relationship

Comment: Just an `Observation` of my own, do you really need all those relations? Seems like all of those `has_one` relations could just be fields in the `Observation` model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Observation.has_one :rainfall`, so it should be:

```
<%= obs.rainfall.value %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the error now changes to:   undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass

Comment: use `<%= obs.rainfall.try(:value) %>`

Comment: @user2851268 that means there's no `rainfall` associated with at least one of `observations` records. Either make sure there is always `rainfall` associated, or follow Nithin's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Nithin that works perfectly!! Could you possibly explain why the .try(:value) worked? Just saw Marek's comment, thanks everyone, make sense now.....you have saved me hours more hair pulling. thanks!!

Comment: @user2851268 `try(:value)` calls method `value` if object is present, returns `nil` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have one to one relationship, not has_many. Replace

```
 <%= obs.rainfalls.value %>
```

by

```
 <%= obs.rainfall.value %>
```